# SSRF exploitation using MIME Type response

Tags: ssrf

My website has an upload form for avatar, you can either upload image directly from PC or either make website grab it from another host.
If the MIME Type is wrong , the response will contain the following:
`{"status":"wrong_mime","mime":"text\/html;}`
The application is running on Amazon AWS, and ,from [SSRF Attack on AWS](https://ab-lumos.medium.com/ssrf-attack-on-aws-technical-demo-for-stealing-ec2-metadata-4910dafafdee) I have read that if a vulnerable website returns info, then you can grab valuable things. My question is, if my application returns the MIME type of the file which my website tried to acccess, could someone exploit it?
If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSRF exploitation vulnerability is from EC2 applications that allow AWS metadata URLs as input, and then renders the results. Does your app allow a URL like the one below as input?

`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials`

That URL when fetched from inside the server will return sensitive EC2 metadata, in this case active security credentials. Make sure your app does not render that data or return it to the browser.

The response you show does not indicate there's any vulnerability it would have to return data from the requested URL for it to be vulnerable. Check your error handling handling and data validation, and exclude ec2 metadata urls from being accepted.